# List item background changed color while hover

Tags: html, css, hover, listitem

Hi I have a problem using list item on the side bar.

I use image inside the list item for navigation bar and whenever I hover over the image, there is a white background appear behind the image and I don't know how to fix this.

Please help me.

Here is the screenshot of the screen
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54cAl.png)

And here is the code

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

                <li><a href="#"><img src="Side_Bar_BackToTop.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="Side_Bar_About.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="Side_Bar_History.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="Side_Bar_Movie.png"></a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: block;
padding: 20px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
background-color: #905c2a;
border-right: 1px solid #eee;
width: 200px;
[}

.nav-sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: -20px;

}

.nav-sidebar li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav-sidebar li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-sidebar li  img:hover{
    border-top: 2px solid #f4d37f;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f4d37f;
}][1]
```

Comment: post your fiddle / snippet so that we can check it?

Comment: here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/4px1o6q9/

Comment: did the answer below help you? Please voteup / mark as correct and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using bootstrap. Please let me know whether this is what you expected. Thanks!

Here is the fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1gxruoj/)

Added the following style to remove the background behind the image:

```
.nav-sidebar li a:focus, .nav-sidebar li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exact the problem with boostrap. So I fixed the elements in Bootstrap and the problem is solved. :D

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct to acknowledge that the answer works for you? Thanks!